# Activeadmin set resource's attributes on action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I want to set a default value for an attribute of the activeadmin resource, so when it renders the form, it will use this value.
e.g.: in the action new, I want to set the attribute *product* of the object *order* , so the form will come with the product already selected(but leting it to be changed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the value to the form field as follows:

```
  f.inputs do
    f.input :product, input_html: { value: products_value }
```

Comment: Oh..When I tried to add directly in the input, I was using
    f.inputs do
      f.input :product, value: products_value
without the input_html.
Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted Andrey Deineko's answer, but even before I saw it, I've done it in another way:
    controller do
      def new
        @resource_name = ResourceName.new(...)

so, I just defined the action method inside the block controller, creating an instance of the resource with an instance variable named as the ActiveAdmin Resource name.